# See question when answering

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app

Right now in the iOS app, I have to save my answer as a draft in order to view the question. Since I'm often referring back to the question, this is inconvenient and less friendly than the old app (although many other things are improved!)

I would love to be able to glance back, either by scrolling up, by showing the Q on the right, or any other means.

Thanks for the awesome app and community!

Comment: Right now your flow is 1) tap close, 2) scroll through and read the question, 3) scroll back to the bottom and tap "Add an answer", 4) tap "Resume", 5) scroll through your answer and continue editing.  What I envision is 1) tap "Close", a bar appears at the bottom of the screen saying "Draft saved, tap to continue", 2) scroll to the question, read, 3) tap the bar to get the same screen with your cursor in place.

Comment: On iPad, we could try to switch between the answer preview (on the right) and the question itself, without having to leave the editor at all.

Comment: @ArieLitovsky Ugh, I don't even want to think about the logistics of that one. What if someone wants to get details from an answer or a specific comment? Or a new answer comes in? We'd have to spawn a whole new copy of the question controller, probably with interaction disabled or else we have to keep the two in synch, deal with nav, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is now in the App Store.  Tapping "Back" (used to be cancel) will take you to the question and you can then tap the drafting widget in the top right corner of the screen to get back right where you left off.

Comment: Yes, I noticed this last week but forgot that I formally requested it. Thanks, love it!